# Freebsd pfctl firewall problem

Tags: freebsd, firewall

I want to block port 3306 for everyone in bsd system and open it for one ip address using a firewall in the freebsd.

I tried something like this but the port closes and the addresses are not open.

```
## our interface ##
ext_if="em0"

## do not block mysqld on ##
mysqld_ip="{ !202.54.1.2, !202.54.1.10, !202.54.1.15 }" <<< don't open when i write address ip

## Block everything for tcp port number 3306 except $mysqld_ip  ###
block in on $ext_if proto tcp from any to  $mysqld_ip port 3306
```

Does anyone know how to make this firewall work well?

Answer (score 2):

Last rule to match a packet wins unless the rule is specialized with `quick`.

So this is what I would do

```
mysqld_ip="{ 202.54.1.2, 202.54.1.10, 202.54.1.15 }"
pass in quick on $ext_if inet proto tcp from any to $mysqld_ip port 3306 keep state
block in on $ext_if inet proto tcp from any to any port 3306
```